# Autocomplete with Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, autocomplete

I'm developing a new sample Application using Core Data that stores **"CountryNames"** into one Entity (named **"Country"**) with **"CountryID"** and **"CountryCode"**. I added around `200 Countries` to the Entity **"Country"** with their **"Names"**, **"ID"** and **"Codes"**(I succeeded till Now).

Now, I want to perform **"Auto complete"** functionality with this Entity (named **"Country"**). I want to fetch all the `Records` having the `Country Name` (named `cName` in `Entity`) start with some `Prefix` (I typed in `UITextField` named `txtCname`).

**Fetch Request :**

```
- (IBAction)findCountry:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [del managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *fr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fr setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cName beginswith[c] %@",txtCname.text];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *objects = [moc executeFetchRequest:fr error:&error];
    NSLog(@"object :: %@",objects);
    if (objects.count == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"No Match Found.");
    }
    else
    {
        con = objects[0];
        NSLog(@"cName :: %@",con.cName);
        NSLog(@"cID :: %@",con.cID);
        NSLog(@"cCode :: %@",con.cCode);
    }
}
```

I wrote **"U"** in `UITextField`. But, It's not giving me the Result with the Country Names started with **"U"**.

So, **can anyone tell me if I am on the right way or not ?**

Comment: These links might be informative for you [iOS full-text search with Core Data and SQLite](http://blog.lunatech.com/2013/01/24/ios-core-data-sqlite-full-text-search) and [Searching For Speedy Searching](http://swwritings.com/post/2013-04-30-searching-for-speedy-searching)

Comment: @Anupdas: Thanks for the Response & Links. Can you tell me the Predicate I have written is correct or not ?

Comment: so the country name field in your Country entity is called cName? Also try to use `BEGINSWITH` instead of small `beginswith`?

Comment: @verbumdei : Ans of your 1st Que : YES and Ans of your 2nd Que : didn't work.

Comment: @Vin: Perhaps you should show more code (the complete fetch request).

Comment: @MartinR : I have updated my Question. Check it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some things to check:**

**1)** Are you indeed setting the predicate on the query ?

Like, `[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];`

**2)** You talk about setting the U in `textField` - but you use `txtCname.text` in your predicate statement - is that the right field that indeed contains your starting letter ?

**3)** What data DO you get from the query if not the desired country list ?

Comment: @Vin: As I just noticed, the correct answer was already given by TheEye, so perhaps you could accept his answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to assign the predicate to the fetch request:

```
NSFetchRequest *fr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fr setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cName beginswith[c] %@",txtCname.text];

// ADD THIS LINE:
[fr setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, that was the silly mistake by me. I have just started to use Core Data. Can you tell me some good ways to learn it fundamentally ?

Comment: @Vin: As I just noticed, the correct answer was already given by TheEye, so perhaps you could accept his answer instead.

Comment: yeah sure. Can you give me the answer of the Question , i asked in my previous Comment and also if you can tell me what I am doing for autocomplete is right or is there any other optimum way to do it ? Pls Suggest me...